# jQuery mouseleave function isn't being triggered when mouse moves quickly

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have a timeline with little pins on it which when hovered over, slide up or down and then display a caption. When the mouse leaves, the caption should disappear and the pin moves back. This works, but with the code I am using, if the mouse moves too quickly, it doesn't detect the mouse leave. How can I fix this?

P.S, the only reason I am using mouse enter/leave is because I think I needed to use live() as my elements are added dynamically after the document loads.

```
    $('#about-me .progress-bar .progress .notes li.personal').live('mouseenter',function(){
    $(this).animate({
        top:25
    }, 200, function(){
        $(this).find('.caption').stop(true, true).fadeIn(200);
    });     
}).live('mouseleave',function(){
    $(this).find('.caption').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeOut(200,function(){
        $(this).parents('li').animate({
            top:30
        },200);         
    });
});
```

Comment: when you say it doesn't detect the mouseleave- if you replace the mouseleave function with `alert('test')` does this not fire at all?

Comment: Oh, it does :( 

The caption just doesn't fade out and the pin doesn't animate >.<

Comment: Any idea why this could be happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT**

Okay new plan!

Try this:

```
$('#about-me .progress-bar .progress .notes li.personal').live('mouseenter',function(){
    $(this).animate({
        top:25
    }, 200, function(){
        $(this).find('.caption').stop(true, true).fadeIn(200);
    });     
}).live('mouseleave',function(){
    $(this).stop(true, true).find('.caption').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeOut(200,function(){
        $(this).parents('li').animate({
            top:30
        },200);         
    });
});
```

I didn't click that you are running animations on two separate objects! Feeling more confident about this one!

Comment: They still get stuck on unfortunately. They don't if if I move my mouse slowly though.

Comment: try changing `.stop(true, true).fadeIn` to `.stop().fadeIn` - this seems to have corrected the behaviour in my test - probably has a knock on though

Comment: You genius! Saved me a right headache. Can I ask how you got to that fix? I know you added the stop() before the find(), but why?

Thanks again, appreciate it.

Comment: Woot! glad it worked! So what was happening is the animate duration was still active when the mouse left the element, lets say with a maximum of 190 ms remaining. The call back of this would therefore run before the fadeOut and calling `.stop(true, true)` removes any queued functions (which in this case is the fadeOut and its callback). So by adding a `stop()` to the `$(this)` element we prevent the initial callback from firing! At least that's how it works in my mind :D

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this before.  When you move the mouse fast enough, it just skips over to a new place and doesn't trigger the mouseleave action.  here's my solution using just a little bit of jQuery.  Basically, while you are hovering on the pin, you need to bind a listener to the window that looks for any mouse movement and checks that you are still hovering on the pin.  I dont' think you'd want this listener running all the time, so I have it unbind itself.

```
$(".pin").live("mouseenter", function(event) {
  var pin = $(event.target);
  // show the caption
  pin.addClass("hovered");  

  $(window).bind("mousemove", function(event) {
    var target = $(event.target);
    if (!target.hasClass("hovered")) {
      // hide the caption      
      $(".hovered").removeClass("hovered");
      $(window).unbind("mousemove");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer muirbot, this actually helped me with something else but Inrbob's answer fixed this question.