# mouseleave is not working as it should be

Tags: jquery, mouseleave

I use mouseenter and mouseleave for larger image when you hover your mouse on it. If the mouse is moved too quickly, mouseleave does not work, and the magnified image remains.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.productImg').bind('mouseenter', function(){
        if(!$('#zoom_product_image').length){
            var maxWidth=$(this).parents('form').width();
            var maxHeight=$(this).parents('form').height();

            var link=this.src.replace(/small/g, 'big');
            $(this).parents('form').append('<img id="zoom_product_image" style="display: none;" src="'+link+'">');
            var img=new Image();
            img.onload=function(){
                $('#zoom_product_image').css({'position': 'absolute', 'border': '1px solid #78C7FF', 'top': '0px', 'left': '0px', 'z-index': '10000', 'opacity': '0.95', 'cursor': 'pointer'});
                $('#zoom_product_image').fadeIn(200);

                if($('#zoom_product_image').width()>maxWidth){
                    $('#zoom_product_image').css({'width': maxWidth, 'height': $('#zoom_product_image').height()*(maxWidth/$('#zoom_product_image').width())});
                }
                if($('#zoom_product_image').height()>maxHeight){
                    $('#zoom_product_image').css({'height': maxHeight, 'width': $('#zoom_product_image').width()*(maxHeight/$('#zoom_product_image').height())});
                }
            }
            img.src=link;

            $('#zoom_product_image').bind('mouseleave', function(){
                $('#zoom_product_image').detach();
            });

            $('#zoom_product_image').bind('click', function(){
                window.location.href=$('#zoom_product_image').parent().find('.bigtitle').attr('href');
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You may need to move the `mouseleave` and `click` events outside of the `mouseenter` event.

Comment: Do you happen to have a working example on http://jsfiddle.net/, if not would you be able to create a simple one to show exactly what you're experiencing?

Comment: Unfortunately jsfiddle stopped working and work and home.
I can give the link to the original.

Comment: The original will be fine, I'm sure someone will be able to figure out the issue from it =) Also, this question seems similar any may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6144349/jquery-mouseleave-function-isnt-being-triggered-when-mouse-moves-quickly

Comment: [http://devluntegg.fishok.getmyip.com:39875/voblery-asakura-kitay.html](http://devluntegg.fishok.getmyip.com:39875/voblery-asakura-kitay.html)
The link I didn't find anything useful: (

Comment: Thank you, deal with the problem myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.productImg').bind('mouseenter', function(){
        if($('#zoom_product_image').length)
            $('#zoom_product_image').detach();

        var maxWidth=$(this).parents('form').width();
        var maxHeight=$(this).parents('form').height();

        var link=this.src.replace(/small/g, 'big');
        $(this).parents('form').append('<img id="zoom_product_image" style="display: none;" src="'+link+'">');
        var img=new Image();
        img.onload=function(){
                $('#zoom_product_image').css({'position': 'absolute', 'border': '1px solid #78C7FF', 'top': '0px', 'left': '0px', 'z-index': '10000', 'opacity': '0.95', 'cursor': 'pointer', 'display': 'block'});

                if($('#zoom_product_image').width()>maxWidth){
                    $('#zoom_product_image').css({'width': maxWidth, 'height': $('#zoom_product_image').height()*(maxWidth/$('#zoom_product_image').width())});
                }
                if($('#zoom_product_image').height()>maxHeight){
                    $('#zoom_product_image').css({'height': maxHeight, 'width': $('#zoom_product_image').width()*(maxHeight/$('#zoom_product_image').height())});
                }
        }
        img.src=link;

        $(this).parents('form').bind('mouseleave', function(){
            $('#zoom_product_image').detach();
        });

        $('#zoom_product_image').bind('click', function(){
            window.location.href=$('#zoom_product_image').parent().find('.bigtitle').attr('href');
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Also consider loading the images first and then binding the events after they're loaded.

Another tip is to use the jQuery hover function (works the same, other than it may be somewhat easier to read):

```
$(".productImg").hover(
    function() {
        // do mouse enter things
    },
    function() {
        // do mouse leave things
    }
);
```

And put this inside the onload event:

```
img.onload = function() {
    $(".productImg").hover(..);
};
```